# Rotating a Skinned Model's bones correctly? XNA

Tags: c#, xna

How do I rotate a Skinned Model's bones around itself instead of the model's origin?

In the `SkinningSample`, when I rotate the dude's forearm it rotates around what appears to be the model's origin.  I would like to rotate bones around their own origins if possible.

The description for `GetSkinTransforms()` says :

> "Gets the current bone transform matrices, relative to the skinning
>   bind pose."

So I suspect that may be the problem.  Does anyone know how to convert these transforms into what they need to be?

Here is part of the `SkinningSample`.

```
  float rotation = 0;
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        HandleInput();

        UpdateCamera(gameTime);

        animationPlayer.UpdateWorldTransforms(Matrix.Identity);
        animationPlayer.UpdateSkinTransforms();

        Matrix RotationTransform = Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(rotation, 0, 0) ;
        animationPlayer.GetSkinTransforms().SetValue(RotationTransform, 34); 

        rotation = rotation + .1f;
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice device = graphics.GraphicsDevice;

        device.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        Matrix[] bones = animationPlayer.GetSkinTransforms();

        // Compute camera matrices.
        Matrix view = Matrix.CreateTranslation(0, -40, 0) * 
                      Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(cameraRotation)) *
                      Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.ToRadians(cameraArc)) *
                      Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0, 0, -cameraDistance), 
                                          new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Vector3.Up);

        Matrix projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4,
                                                                device.Viewport.AspectRatio,
                                                                1,
                                                                10000);

        // Render the skinned mesh.
        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in currentModel.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (SkinnedEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {
                effect.SetBoneTransforms(bones);

                effect.View = view;
                effect.Projection = projection;

                effect.EnableDefaultLighting();

                effect.SpecularColor = new Vector3(0.25f);
                effect.SpecularPower = 16;
            }

            mesh.Draw();
        }

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to transform the boneTransform not the skinTransform.  I just created another method in the AnimationPlayer class to allow this manipulation:

```
public void TransformBone(Matrix BoneAlteration, int BoneID)
{
    boneTransform[BoneID] = BoneAlteration * bindPose[BoneID];
    UpdateWorldTransforms(Matrix.Identity);
    UpdateSkinTransforms();
}
```

So if I wanted to rotate a bone I'd call this method to create the correct skinTransformation Matrix.  This assumes that the other boneTransforms are set in their correct position.  I also think you could replace bindPose with boneTransform if you wish to rotate about an already rotated bone.